# Force autocompletions to trigger in unsupported apps/websites

Tags: macos, auto-complete

I use autocompletions extensively. For example, I have emojis set to replace text such as "elaugh" for "", or fill out my email when I type "@@". I also have some LaTeX character autocompletions enabled. It makes typing a lot easier.

However, I've noticed that in some apps and websites such as WeChat and Discord (via Brave Browser), these autocompletions don't trigger. Unfortunately, this also coincides with sites and apps where I would make extensive use of such autocompletions.

Is there a way to force these autocompletions to trigger in these apps where they are unsupported?

Comment: Probably write the code to support autocompletion.

Comment: To complete @SolarMike answer : auto completion is more autocorrection using your dictionary . So it works only for text entry which are flagged as use autocorrect ´ . For example autocorrection is not enabled on password or username fields.